# What’s the price scaling for businesses?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

So, I’ve been playing Adventure Capitalist for about 2 weeks. I’m pretty slow at idles so I only have 150k angels. And I keep wondering, what is the price scale? There can’t be one singular algorithm because newspaper stands cost more then oil companies after ~300 buys, so what are the algorithms for the price increase of the businesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see here](http://adventure-capitalist.wikia.com/wiki/Earth) there is a coefficient. This coefficient is the increase in price after buying another business (lemonade stand/news paper/etc). As you can see, the coefficient for news paper is the highest, 1.15, which confirms your observation in comparison with Oil Company, which is 1.07.

So in short, the 'scaling' for each business is:

- Lemonade Stand   1.07
- Newspaper Delivery   1.15
- Car Wash 1.14
- Pizza Delivery   1.13
- Donut Shop   1.12
- Shrimp Boat  1.11
- Hockey Team  1.10
- Movie Studio 1.09
- Bank 1.08
- Oil Company  1.07